# Debug child ruby cgi process spawned by webrick by redirecting stdin and stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cgi, webrick, byebug

The problem: byebug or pry output is returning via HTTP instead of on console.

I have a *webrick.rb* script which has a CGIHandler mounted with a *dispatch.fcgi* script passed to it:

> server.mount("/", WEBrick::HTTPServlet::CGIHandler, File.expand_path(File.dirname(**FILE**))+"/dispatch.fcgi")

Thus, webrick passes each HTTP request to this script via the _do_GET_ method.

This method spawns a subprocess using IO::popen as per this code snippet from

*/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpservlet*/cgihandler.rb

```rb
class CGIHandler < AbstractServlet
      Ruby = RbConfig.ruby # :nodoc:
      CGIRunner = "\"#{Ruby}\" \"#{WEBrick::Config::LIBDIR}/httpservlet/cgi_runner.rb\"" # :nodoc:

      ##
      # Creates a new CGI script servlet for the script at +name+

      def initialize(server, name)
        super(server, name)
        @script_filename = name
        @tempdir = server[:TempDir]
        @cgicmd = "#{CGIRunner} #{server[:CGIInterpreter]}"
      end

      # :stopdoc:

      def do_GET(req, res)
        cgi_in = IO::popen(@cgicmd, "wb")
```

When I use *byebug* or *binding.pry* in the source code files, their *stdout* is returned to the parent process which is then returned eventually by the *dispatch.fcgi* script and thus returned via HTTP. Obviously this is useless as I cannot interact with it.

To fix this, my idea is to have byebug rather use different IO streams rather than stdout and stdin or otherwise redirect it somehow to a different file descriptor under /dev/pts . Then, I can write a small console.rb script to interact with those file descriptors/IO streams instead and in this way I'm able to interact with byebug or pry.

I am new to ruby, byebug/pry and webrick and my idea sounds over complicated. I don't really know how to achieve this (e.g. how do I create new file descriptors in OS) and I'm sure there must be some easier way than to hack the byebug/pry gems and mess with the OS?
The resources out there to debug CGI are very slim.

Comment: [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) might work for your use-case

Comment: yeah I also thought maybe using TCP sockets instead, but was hoping someone has solved a similar challenge in a simpler manner that I'm not thinking of. But pry-remote seems worth a try

Comment: pry-remote uses TCP to allow you to connect to the pry session remotely (it uses [DRb](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html), which internally uses TCP).

Comment: Thanks @Turtlefight, you pointed me in the right direction. I searched for byebug remote debugging and used https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md, works great. I had tunnel vision after spending hours to get things working my way, so the answer was simple in the end.